# Visibility of the renamed first column

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, permissions, rename, title

In SharePoint I renamed the first column which is by default named as TITLE. The problem is that I am the only one who is able to see the renamed column but everybody else still sees is as TITLE.

How could this be solved?

Comment: This is strange! Can you please add the steps you followed to rename the title column? Also, ask other users to open the list in new browser session and check again.

Comment: Follow steps in my answer to rename the list column. After renaming, check on other user's system if it is changed. Also make sure you are checking on the same site and in same list (in case if you are checking in another list by mistake).

Comment: Let me know if this works for you or you still facing this issue.

Comment: Ganesh Sanap in both cases, other users still see the first column as a TITLE. All the other columns they see as they should, the change is just not visible for the first column.

Comment: Can you please add any screenshots of what you are seeing and what other users are seeing if possible? That will help us understand if you are checking it write or not?

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps to change the column name:

**Method 1**:

1. Select **Settings** (Gear Icon) --> **List Settings**.
2. Scroll down to **Columns** section, click on **Title** column.
3. Under the **Column Name**, type in the new name for a column.
4. Click **OK** at the bottom.
5. The column will now have a new, custom name.

**Method 2 (For SharePoint Online/2019)**:

1. Go to the SharePoint list.
2. Select a small drop-down icon next to column name.
3. Click on **Column settings** --> and then **Rename**.
4. Type new name for your column and then **Save**.

[image]